# Displaying table columns below of each other for small displays (responsive layout)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

I have a table with two columns:

```
-------------
|  A  |  B  |
-------------
```

I the browser width is too small for this layout, it should switch to this layout:

```
-------------
|     A     |
-------------
|     B     |
-------------
```

I got this to work with fixed column width and "float:left":

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 300px; float: left; border: 1px solid black;">This is column 1</td>
            <td style="width: 300px; float: left; border: 1px solid black;">This is column 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, I want the column widths to be "50%", using all the available space, and specifying a "min-width" in pixel, tried the following:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%; min-width: 200px; float: left; border: 1px solid black;">This is column 1</td>
            <td style="width: 50%; min-width: 200px; float: left; border: 1px solid black;">This is column 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, this immediately places the columns below each other, even though there is enough space to put them next to each other. What could I do instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use media queries from css, where you can define a new css for specific width...

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_media_example1

you can see an example of it works.

http://jsbin.com/xozipinila/edit?html,css,output

you can see working demo here, I have used div instead of table.

Comment: Anirudh, just one more thing... I'm just trying to integrate it with my webpage and noticed that once you add more content to one column (multiline), the two columns are not vertically aligned properly. I'd like to have a top-align... Any way to do that?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out: Add "vertical-align: top;" to the child style